# getting sum of a set of a particular element in a set of lists in python

Tags: python, list

Suppose i have a list which contains sublists :

```
THELIST = [
  ['0', 'xb', '"OZNG15"', '23', '50', 'P'],
  ['0', 'vcxbv', '"OZNG15"', '23', '-100', 'P'],
  ['0', 'grfds', '"OZNG15"', '23', '412', 'P']
]
```

How do I calculate the sum of elements in the 5th position of each list ( i.e. 50-100+412 = 362 )

Comment: Post the code of what you tried already.

Comment: line3 = [ int(x) for x in line2[4:5]  ]

    print line3
    print sum( int(i) for i in line2[4:5])

Comment: @DPatel What's line3 and line2?

Comment: line2 = [x for x in line if x]

Comment: line3 = [ int(x) for x in line2[4:5]  ]

Comment: and line is THELIST here

Comment: Please *edit your question* with that information. And use consistent naming. People are unlikely to help if you make it difficult for them.

Comment: @DPatel Speaking of your actual problem: Why do you do `line2[4:5] `? This will return a `list` of one element, namely `[line[4]]`. Iterating over that just adds overhead to unpack what shouldn't be packed in the first place. `line2 = sum(int(x[4]) for x in THELIST if x)` is equivalent and faster - and equivalent to MosesKoledoye's answer. So what is your actual problem? Does it not work? Then post the error message. Is it slow? Then provide more context, and consider profiling.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ive simplified my question. Please help me out on this if possible

Comment: @DPatel The answer by MosesKoledoye provides the correct result for your stated problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this with a generator expression and `sum`:

```
output = sum(int(lst[4]) for lst in THELIST)
```

Comment: @DPatel why not? It is appropriate for the information you provided in the question.